# Execution of program stops and no errors are generated

Tags: java

I got this code

```
// "status" is a JLabel field

status.setText(" Download data ");
url = new URL( baseURL );
FileUtils.copyURLToFile( url, tempFile );
status.setText(" Download done... ");
```

When code is run, the "status" gets updated with: Download data

The file downloads, and I can see it when I open the "tempFile" in notepad. (tempFile.txt)

The next status update i.e "Download Done", never gets executed, and all the code that follows also doesn't get executed...

The Exception e.printStackTrace() is also empty...

What is goin gon here?

PS, the file downloaded is just a plain text file with about 2000 lines of text in it...
And I can see all of it in the temporary file I created tempFile (tempFile.txt)

I also commented all the code that follows after the second update, but still nothing.

Currently I'm downloading the file from localhost/data.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [copyUrlToFile(url,file)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File))

> Warning: this method does not set a connection or read timeout **and thus might block forever**. Use [copyURLToFile(URL, File, int, int)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File,%20int,%20int)) with reasonable timeouts to prevent this.

There could be several explanations for why the download doesn't complete. Perhaps there is a step in the protocol that triggers at the end of the transfer that requires the use of a port your system is currently blocking.

Comment: Hi, I also tried this, but still doesn't work... FileUtils.copyURLToFile( url, tempFile , 1000, 1000); Is there an easier non-apache-dependant way of reading a file from server? Possibly line by line? Thanks

Comment: Found a good example here to read URL without apache.commons.io: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-url-java-url-class-example-code